# Get json object with value with python for loop

Tags: python, json

When I use:

```
for reports in raw_data:
        for names in reports["names"]:
                report_name = json.dumps(names).strip('"')
                report_names.append(report_name)
```

I get the key/object name: 'report1', ...

When I use:

```
for reports in raw_data:
        for names in reports["names"].values():
                report_name = json.dumps(names).strip('"')
                report_names.append(report_name)
```

I get the value of the object: 'name1', ...

How do get the object and value together, for example: 'report1': 'name1', ...

The json:

```
[
  {
    "names": {
      "report1": "name1",
      "report2": "name2"
    }
  },
  {
    "names": {
      "report3": "name3",
      "report4": "name4"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each dictionary in the object, then extract each key: value pair from `items()`:

```
data = [
  {
    "names": {
      "report1": "name1",
      "report2": "name2"
    }
  },
  {
    "names": {
      "report3": "name3",
      "report4": "name4"
    }
  }
]

for d in data:
    for k, v in d["names"].items():
        print(k, v)
```

Result:

```
report1 name1
report2 name2
report3 name3
report4 name4
```

Or if you can just print out the tuple pairs:

```
for d in data:
    for pair in d["names"].items():
        print(pair)

# ('report1', 'name1')
# ('report2', 'name2')
# ('report3', 'name3')
# ('report4', 'name4')
```

If you want all of the pairs in a list, use a *list comprehension*:

```
[pair for d in data for pair in d["names"].items()]
# [('report1', 'name1'), ('report2', 'name2'), ('report3', 'name3'), ('report4', 'name4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import json
with open(r'jsonfile.json', 'r') as f:
        qe = json.load(f)
        for item in qe:
            if item == 'name1': 
                print(qe)
```